# Convert A Javascript Button Function To An Onload Function

Tags: javascript, onload, scrolltop, onload-event

I have a nicely working 'scrolltop' script that works fine throughout my site.

However, it is a 'button' function script.

In some cases, I need to execute this script from being a button function to an 'onload' function.

I'm not verse enough to be able to convert the script. If anyone can advise me on how to do that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script (button function):

```
    <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn"><span class="BtnText">Page Top<span></button>

    <script>
    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()}; function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";} 
    else {document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";}}
    function topFunction() {document.body.scrollTop = 0; document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;} 
    </script>
```

Comment: Read tag description before using them: java and javascript are two totally different languages.

Comment: Thank you for the criticism Backslash. Any knowledge on the issue?

Comment: what "onload" function means? And what do you mean with "in some cases"?

Comment: @quirimmo... basically... when the page loads, I need it to be scrolled to the top.

Comment: `window.onload = function() { scrollFunction(); };`

Comment: I acknowledged the criticism. If that's all you've got post-point, please move along.

Comment: There's nothing in the function that cares about what element or event invoked it. What's problem are you having assigning it to the load event?

Comment: Thank you quirimmo. I'll give that a shot. Very much appreciated.

Comment: or `topFunction()` instead of `scrollFunction()`. I didn't understand what's the name of the function you use for scrolling.

Comment: @Quentin.... the whole function (as it is) is assigned to a 'getElementby Id', so actually that's pretty specific.

Comment: @JamieSexton — No, it isn't (assigned that way)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if you meant to execute the function `topFunction()` when the page loads.

But, if that's the case:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  topFunction();
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};
function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
  }
}
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot now and let ya know how it went. I was wondering though, if there is a way to shorten that script and remove the 'button' part of it. But I'm gonna try it as you edited it and see if that works.

Comment: If you want to scroll to the top of the page when it loads, without having to click a button, you can safely remove the button from your html and use this script.

Comment: Thanks man. Unfortunately, it didn't work. But I don't think it's a flaw in the script. It's a flaw in my understanding of what I actually need to happen. 

I have an 'index' page with an iframe.. ' id="mainFrame" ' in which all of my site content is displayed. 

I am using two different 'scroll' functions in that 'index' page.

One of them is the 'topFunction', button executed script I included in the question. That works fine.

Also, in the 'mainFrame' iframe tags, I am using the onload="scroll(0,0)" function. Which also works fine.

Comment: Where I am running into issues is....

I have a page on my site which has it's own nav bar and content iframe.

I tried using the onload="scroll(0,0)" in that iframe as well. 

Unfortunately... that is NOT working. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to execute the function "topFunction" to the iframe content from the page? In that case, it wouldn't work becuase of security and cross-origin reasons. For example: it would be dangerous if anyone could include an iframe of google and execute a script from their own website.

Comment: I see. So, if I exclude the whole idea of executing that particular script to get the inner iframe's content to start at the top (on page load)... Is there a way for me to do that? Like I said... I already tried using the onload="scroll(0,0)" that I am using on the index page's iframe. No luck.

Comment: To do that, just make a `<script>` tag in the iframe's source code, and put the function `topFunction` in the script. And do `window.onload` just like what you did in this script.

Comment: I have never put a script tag in an iframe's source code. How would that even look?

Comment: Are suggesting that I put that 'topFunction' script in the head of the 'content' pages that are to be displayed in the second frame? Or.....?

Comment: Hi, what I meant was put the script tag in the html file you used for the iframe.

Comment: I gave it a shot. Didn't seem to work. I may be doing it wrong.